# How to optimize many dom reflow operations caused by getComputedStyle?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, reflow

I'm building solution for business PDF like HTML elements splitting based on their content height which can be used for example - with puppeter/wkhtmltopdf to render suitable layout as much similar with my HTML/JS solution as possible. My goal is also to create unlimited to margins/padding/box-sizing way to styling it in CSS.

For better explanation, imagine *div* container with constant height, *1000px* for example, but content is unlimited, and everytime its sum will take more than thats *div* specified height, we have to clone that page with appriopriate layout and content which overflows its boundary.

One of use cases is to use it in React because it has very high possibility to make it fancy with his reactive functionalities (Live pdf preview). But building it with react was such a pain, so I decided to create it in plain javascript.

I'm watching for DOM update using **MutationObserver**

```js
    private _initOnDomUpdateEvents(observer: Element, callback?: () => any) {
        const mutation = new MutationObserver(() => {
            callback();
        });

        mutation.observe(observer, {
            attributes: true,
            subtree: true,
            childList: true
        })

        this.watchers.push(mutation);

        return mutation;
    }
```

And everytime the **DOM** has ben updated in observer scope (for example in *.css* selector named `.sheet`), I'm creating tree of its children which contains details about their relative height, offsetY, margins, paddings, borders, box-sizing, overflow and display - It has to be very accurate, pixel perfect almost. But to archive this, I've used very expansive solution, and optimisation gives me headache everytime I think of it.

To imagine my problem, look at this.

```js
class Tree {
    public getElementTree(element: Element): TreeElement {
        const main = Tree._getChildrenBoundaryDetails(element, element);

        main.setChildren(Tree._buildDimensionsTree(main, element));

        return main;
    }

    private static _buildDimensionsTree(parent: TreeElement, element: Element) {
        return Array.from(element.children).map(e => {
            const dimensions = Tree._getChildrenBoundaryDetails(parent.getDomElement(), e)

            dimensions.setChildren(Array.from(e.children).map(e => Tree._getChildrenBoundaryDetails(parent.getDomElement(), e)))

            return dimensions;
        })
    }


    private static _getChildrenBoundaryDetails(parent: Element, element: Element): TreeElement {
        const style = getComputedStyle(element);

        const offsetHeightTop = element.getBoundingClientRect().top
            - parent.getBoundingClientRect().top;

        return new TreeElement({
            borderBox: style.boxSizing === 'border-box',
            element: element,
            offsetY: {
                from: offsetHeightTop,
                to: offsetHeightTop + parseFloat(style.height)
            },
            margin: {
                top: parseFloat(style.marginTop),
                bottom: parseFloat(style.marginBottom)
            },
            padding: {
                top: parseFloat(style.paddingTop),
                bottom: parseFloat(style.paddingBottom),
            },
            border: {
                top: parseFloat(style.borderTopWidth),
                bottom: parseFloat(style.borderBottomWidth)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Do you see that recursion in `Tree._buildDimensionsTree`? It's terrifying if you imagine, how many children may exists in real world examples, and for each, you have to call `window.getComputedStyle`. So I'm comming with question.

**How to create more CPU friendly solution which don't requires as many *DOM Reflows* as in my example.**

Thank you for help.

Comment: Have you actually profiled this? I don't expect this to trigger multiple reflows. Sure, you're calling `getComputedStyle` and `getBoundClientRect` quite often, but you never change the dom in between, right?

Comment: Btw, have you considered [using print stylesheets](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/05/print-stylesheets-in-2018/) instead?

Comment: I was reading about this topic many times before and didn't find any useful solution for me, that means, basically It's very useful, but when you want something, what is not just another use case of print api, for example elements that should be on every page, but also not fixed positioned, nor set using footer/header template like - footer which boundaries and position is specified by cascade/flexbox layout, it's seems to be unreachable using just print stylesheet. So that's where my idea comes from.

Comment: Answering your first question, Basicaly no and yes. In perfect world I would keep react on props change without blocking it from instant updating, but probably I have to make throttle for that to not overload users browser. So if i dont figure out how to make it better, the compromise becomes only solution.

Comment: And of course, finally I will use print stylesheet, to manually create pages splitting (break-after: always) and set their content (using my solution).